# Extinction probability in a population with competition

Tags: probability, limits, stochastic-processes, asymptotics

Suppose we have a colony of bacteria. At the end of each day, each bacterium produces an exact copy of itself with probability $p$ and then dies with probability $q$. However, $q$ is not constant, but a function of $N$, the total number of bacteria:
$$q=p\bigg(1-\frac{1}{N}\bigg)$$
So in larger populations of bacteria, each bacterium is more likely to die (because of competition, say).

To clarify, $N$ counts the number of bacteria before new ones were born. For instance, if there are $2$ bacteria on one day and they both reproduce to form $4$ bacteria, both of them still have exactly $p/2$ chance of dying (not $3p/4$). And the babies that have just been born cannot die immediately.

Let $P_N$ be the probability that a bacteria colony consisting of $N$ bacteria initially eventually goes extinct. Can we find an asymptotic formula for $P_N$? I suspect that we will have
$$P_N\sim \alpha^N$$
for some $\alpha$, but I don’t know how to calculate this constant.

I did manage to figure out that if we keep $q$ constant, then the probability of eventual extinction starting with $N$ bacteria is exactly equal to
$$\bigg(1-\frac{p-q}{p(1-q)}\bigg)^N$$
for $p>q$, and equal to $1$ for $p\le q$. But that problem was much easier because “newborn” bacteria were independent from their parents, whereas in this problem the chance of each bacterium’s survival is dependent on the overall population size.

So, really my question is: what is the value of
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}P_N^{1/N}=\space ?$$

Comment: "..and **then** dies..": do you mean that death can come **only after** reproduction, or independently from that ?

Comment: @GCab Yeah, they occur independently. So that at the end of each day, each bacterium is replaced by two bacteria with probability $p(1-q)$ (reproduces and then doesn’t die), one bacteria with probability $pq + (1-p)(1-q)$ (reproduces and then dies, or doesn’t reproduce or die) and zero bacteria with probability $q(1-p)$ (doesn’t reproduce, and dies).

Comment: @antkam can you tell me if you get this ping? i'm not sure if you can ping someone who hasn't already commented on the post you're pinging them on. anyways, I think you'll find this question interesting :)

Comment: @mathworker21 - thanks, i did not get the ping, but i already saw this question and indeed already commented, in the thread of the Answer below.  :)

Comment: Is the $N$ that enters $q$ the $N$ before or after the copying?

Comment: @celtschk Before the copying.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer dude, why did you unaccept my answer? you of course are perfectly right to do so if you feel my answer is incorrect, but I am quite annoyed that you don't comment anything at all. can you please communicate? I talked with Hans for a long time, and my answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The extinction probability is $1$ for any initial size population and any $p \in (0,1)$ (for $p=0,1$, the extinction probability is obviously $0$). Fix $p \in (0,1)$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that there is some $N_0 \ge 1$ such that the probability of no extinction with initial size $N_0$ is greater than $0$.

Our probability space is with respect to initial population sizes of $N_0$, probability $p$ of reproduction, and probability $p(1-\frac{1}{N})$ probability of death when population size is $N$. Let $s: \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ represent population size ($s(t)$ is size of population on day $t$, $s(0) := N_0$).

.

> Claim 1: $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{t \to \infty} s(t) = \infty | \text{no extinction}\}) = 1$.

**Proof:** For $M \ge 1$, let $E_M := \{\omega \in \Omega : \liminf_{t \to \infty} s(t) = M \text{and no extinction}\}$. Then, since $M$ is a natural number, $P(E_M) \le P(\{\omega \in \Omega : s(t) = M \text{infinitely often}\})$. Note that the probability that the population goes directly from size $M$ to size $0$ is just some constant $c_M \in (0,1)$ depending on $M$. So, if we let $A_n$ denote the event that the population size does not go directly to $0$ after being at $M$ for the $n^{th}$ time, we see that $P(E_M) \le P(\cap_{n \ge 1} A_n) = \lim_{N \to \infty} P(A_1\cap\dots\cap A_N) = \lim_{N \to \infty} P(A_1)P(A_2 | A_1)P(A_3 | A_1,A_2)\dots P(A_N | A_1,\dots, A_{n-1}) = \lim_{N \to \infty} c_M^N = 0$, since [not going directly to $0$ after being at size $M$ for the $n^{th}$ time] does not affect the probability of [directly going to $0$ after being at size $M$ for the $(n+1)^{st}$ time].

.

> Lemma 1: Let $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive integers with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty$. Then, there is a sequence $N_1 < N_2 < \dots$ of positive integers so that, for each $i \ge 1$, there is some $n \ge 1$ with $x_n = N_i$ and $x_m \ge N_i$ for each $m \ge n$.

**Proof:**  Elementary.

.

> Claim 2: For all $N \ge 1$, $\lim_{M \to \infty} P(\text{population size reaches at least $M$ if initial size was $N$ and there are constant probabilities $p$ and $q$ of reproduction and death}) = 1-P(\text{extinction with constant $p,q$ and initial size $N$})$.

**Proof:** Let $F_M$ be the event that the population size reaches at least $M$ if the initial size was $N$ and there are constant probabilities $p$ and $q$ of reproduction and death. By the same proof in claim $1$, $P($ no extinction with constant $p,q$ and initial size $N)\le P(F_M)$ for each $M$. And of course, $\lim_{M \to \infty} P(F_M) = P(\limsup_M F_M) \le P($no extinction with constant $p,q$ and initial size $N)$.  $\square$

.

Now we can define a map $A : \{\text{no extinction}\} \subseteq \Omega \to \{\text{sequences of increasing positive integers}\}$ as follows. Fix an $\omega$ that doesn't lead to extinction. By claim $1$ and Lemma $1$, there are $N_1 < N_2 < \dots$ so that for each $i$, there is some $t$ so that $s(t) = N_i$ and $s(t') \ge N_i$ for all $t' \ge t$. By claim $2$, given any $(\epsilon_i)_i, \epsilon_i > 0$, we may take a subsequence $(\overline{N_1},\overline{N_2},\dots)$ of the sequence $(N_1,N_2,\dots)$ so that $P($ population size reaches at least $\overline{N_{i+1}}$ if initial size was $\overline{N_i}$ and there are constant probabilities $p$ and $q := p(1-\frac{1}{\overline{N_i}})$ of reproduction and death$) \le 1-(1-\frac{p-q}{p(1-q)})^{\overline{N_i}}+\epsilon_i$. Define $A(\omega) = (\overline{N_1},\overline{N_2},\dots)$.

.

We now have all the machinery to finish the argument.

.

Fix $\omega \in \Omega$ that doesn't lead to extinction, and let $(N_1,N_2,\dots) = A(\omega)$. Let $\overline{E}_{N_i,N_{i+1}}$ denote the event of going from a localmin population size of $N_i$ to a localmin population size of $N_{i+1}$ (we say an ordered pair $(N,t)$ is a 'localmin' if (1) $s(t) = N$ and (2) $s(t') \ge N$ for all $t' \ge t$). For each $i$, $P(\overline{E}_{N_i,N_{i+1}}) \le P(\text{population size goes from $N_i$ to $N_{i+1}$}) \le P(\text{population size goes from $N_i$ to $N_{i+1}$ if death probability is constant at $q := p(1-\frac{1}{N_i})$}) \le 1-(1-\frac{p-q}{p(1-q)})^{N_i}+\epsilon_i$, which is at most a constant $c_p < 1$ for all $i \ge 1$, if the $\epsilon_i$'s are small enough. Therefore, $P(\cap_{i \ge 1} \overline{E}_{N_i,N_{i+1}}) = \lim_{J \to \infty} P(\cap_{i=1}^J \overline{E}_{N_i,N_{i+1}}) = \lim_{J \to \infty} P(\overline{E}_{N_1,N_2})P(\overline{E}_{N_2,N_3} | \overline{E}_{N_1,N_2})\dots P(\overline{E}_{N_J,N_{J+1}} | \overline{E}_{N_1,N_2},\dots,\overline{E}_{N_{J-1},N_J}) \le \lim_{J \to \infty} c_p^J = 0$, where we used the fact that the probability of going from a localmin of $N_i$ to $N_{i+1}$ once the size is $N_i$ of course does not depend on the history.

Comment: "So the idea is that for a population to not go extinct, it has to have infinitely many of these $e^{−p}$-probability events occur, which, by Borel-Cantelli, it won't." - So you are saying that population that has nonzero probability of survival, would have to not go extinct infinitely many times [in order to survive] which happens with with $0$ probability, hence probability of survival of such population is $0$?

Comment: @mbartczak the difference is that you sum a geometric series in the problem that the OP talked about, with constant $p,q$. I follow up the thing you quoted with "The issue is that the events of [surviving extinction with initial size 0] are of course not independent as 0 varies". I recommend you read the rigorous proof. The idea used in the rigorous proof is to look at the probability of going from one size $N_1$ to another size $N_2$. If $N_2$ is sufficiently larger than $N_1$, then this probability is basically constant (just depending on $p$), and the events of going from one size

Comment: @mbartczak to a much larger size are indeed independent of one another. if $p$ and $q$ are constant, though, then the probability of going from one size to a much larger size is exponentially small in terms of the first size, so you sum a geometric series. I hope things are more clear now.

Comment: That's not my point. If $q$ didn't vary with population size by applying this kind of argument you would get: nonzero probability of survival $\Rightarrow$ zero probability of survival. The thing is events: $\{\text{attain some state and go extinct/survive}\}$ and $\{\text{attain some state then some other state and go extinct/survive}\}$ are not independent.

Comment: @mbartczak come on. i addressed your point and said some other stuff. I am NOT saying {attain some state and go extinct} and {attain some state and then some other state and go extinct} are independent. I am saying that {go from size $N_1$ to size $N_2$} and {go from size $N_2$ to size $N_3$} are independent. I said this at the end of my first comment and at the beginning of my second comment replying to you. You definitely are concerned about something legitimate -- what I am telling you is that the whole point of my answer is to avoid that legitimate issue.

Comment: @Hans I removed the words "Borel-Cantelli" since they were preventing you from reading what I have been commenting to you and the thing I was trying to convey. By the way, I was referring to the other "Borel-Cantelli" than the one you mentioned in your most recent comment; namely, that $\sum_n P(A_n) = +\infty$ and $(A_n)_n$ independent implies that, almost surely, infinitely many $A_n$ occur. But that is irrelevant -- just look at my most recent edit. It should have everything you need now.

Comment: That is why I request you to write more details to avoid this kind of confusion. It would be clearer to state that the probability that the population goes from size $$ to *eventually* size $0$ is just some constant depending on $$. Also, it should read: $A_n$ representing the event that the population does not go from $M$ *eventually* to $0$ *after* the $n^{th}$ time the population reaches size $M$. $A_n$'s are **not** independent of each other since $A_n\subset A_m, \forall n<m$. Thus the proof fails.

Comment: @Hans I did write the details, just in the comments, not in the answer. Anyways, I understand your objection and tried my best to write my answer to avoid it. Consider the following. Say I made you flip a coin. If it landed tails, you die. If it landed heads, you have to run a mile (half a mile forward and then half a mile backward to that point). If you survived running the mile, you flipped a coin again. Tails - death; heads - another mile and then another coin flip. Etc. Etc. To infinitely survive this process, you must, in particular, have infinitely many INDEPENDENT coin flips land heads.

Comment: @Hans What you are arguing is that the coin flips are not independent, since flipping heads once is necessary to flip future coins. I completely understand that potential argument, but I hope we can agree that it is not valid and that the probability of surviving EACH of the infinitely man coin flips is $0$. The probability that the population never just goes from $M$ to $0$ is $0$ (that is the coin toss here). If you have a way of phrasing the argument I'm conveying to you now, I'd appreciate if you told me. In fact, it's good we're having this discussion now, because it's at the core of my

Comment: @Hans proof later on, with the population size increasing from $N_i$ to $N_{i+1}$. Maybe one could phrase the argument as, rather than the population dying if it goes from $M$ to $0$, it just stays at $M$, and then the events of going from $M$ to $0$ would be independent. Do you like this phrasing? Finally, I propose we delete all of our comments except for this current one, my previous two, and your last one. Please delete if you agree.

Comment: @Hans Actually, I just figured out how to phrase it. You can just say that the probability the population goes from $M$ to $0$ the $n^{th}$ time the population size reaches $M$ GIVEN THAT it didn't go from $M$ to $0$ on any of the previous tries is still that same constant probability. This gives the "independence" (not really independence, as you noted, but I guess something Markovian) required. Let me know if this appeases you.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comments except the last one as you requested. You can yours now. Your current phrasing is still vague and incorrect. What you are looking at is that given that the population starts from $M$ the probability of it revisits $M$. You intend to prove this is less than $1$ by showing the probability of the population reaching $0$ before revisiting $M$ conditioned on it starting from $M$ is nonzero. Neither of these statements is proven.

Comment: @Hans I am not looking at the probability of revisiting $M$, wtf. I don't know how you read my comments and got that conclusion. I genuinely, genuinely do not know how the flipping a coin and running a mile race did not convey to you the idea behind my argument, let alone convince you of it. I will edit my answer to make it fully rigorous to appease you, but, with all due respect, you need to start putting more emphasis on ideas and less on rigor.

Comment: Revisiting is what you should look at. The coin-flipping example is unconvincing precisely because in that example, given that the coin starts from the head (in fact, in this case, it is independent of the starting position), the probability of landing on the tail before landing on the head is positive, and the same is true for the probability of landing on the head before landing on the tail, while the analogous property is not proven for the bacteria population, with the complication of infinite possible states the population could be in.

Comment: @Hans I did. You're worrying wayyyyy too much about irrelevant data. I'll nevertheless edit my answer soon

Comment: This looks wrong, because a birth-and-death process with equal probabilities of birth and death does not tend to zero with certainty, and here, the probability of death is lesser than the probability of birth.

Comment: @Maxence1402 thanks for your response. so you in particular disagree with the OP's result of $\bigg(1-\frac{p-q}{p(1-q)}\bigg)^N$ when $p=q$ for the probability of eventual extinction? what do you think is the probability when $p=q$?

Comment: @Hans how is the probability of landing on tails before heads positive? you die if you flip tails. I don't see a difference between the coin-flipping example and the population example.

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes, because the expected number of bacteria is always strictly positive, also the process converges to a stationary measure, which is not zero.I think I found a pretty simple answer. If $q$ is constant, then $P_N=P_1^N$ and $P_1=p(1-q)P_1^2+(1-p+pq)P_1+(1-p)q$

Comment: @Maxence1402 that's wrong. do $p=q=.3$. you get nonreal solutions for $P_1$.

Comment: Sorry, $P_N=P_1^N$ and $P_1=p(1-q)P_1^2+((1-p)(1-q)+pq)P_1+(1-p)q$, so $P_1=1$ or $P_1=\frac{(1-p)q}{p(1-q)}$. Since $\mathbb{E}(X_1)=1+p-q>0$ ($X_1$ being the expected number of bacteria after one day starting with one), $P_1<1$, leaving only $P_1=\frac{(1-p)q}{p(1-q)}$. Damn, that's OP's result.

Comment: @Maxence1402 I'd really appreciate if you now read my answer. I don't know why it has been being ignored for so long. It is correct.

Comment: In fact, I cannot, see my [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Za96ehm.png)

Comment: Works well on Firefox, I'll be reading tomorrow however, I'm a bit tired and I'm going to sleep.

Comment: @Maxence1402 thanks. [part 1](https://gyazo.com/47f924e49d4ea6b83a38ed88f75c479e) [part 2](https://gyazo.com/3b3c7c236e47bb8db8b641440a06bcbe) [part 3](https://gyazo.com/4abbeb10d20592ff4d665bd948ef64c4). see the history for a summary of the ideas behind the solution if you want.

Comment: Your proof of Claim 1 is still infuriatingly vague. Please define every notion clearly and rigorously. Let us now try to clarify everything one at a time. What do you mean by "directly"? Let the event $B(n,k):= \big\{s(t=0)=N \bigwedge s(t_1)=s(t_2)=\cdots=s(t_n)=s(t_{n+1})=s(t_{n+2})=\cdots=s(t_{n+k})=M$ for some $0<t_1<t_2\cdots <t_{n+k}, n,k\in \mathbf N \bigwedge s(t)\ne M\, \forall t\not\in\{t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_{n+k}\} \bigwedge s(t)>0, \forall t>0\big\}$. Is $B(n,k)\in A_n$? Is $B(n,k=\infty)\in A_n$?

Comment: As for your coin-flip example, the probability of landing on tail (and die and thus by default) before landing on head is just the probability of landing on tail in the very next toss, because as I stated before, there are only two states, head and tail. You yourself stated that the probability of the coin landing on tail at the next toss is positive. Therefore the conclusion.

Comment: @Hans lol. I would usually feel sympathetic to your concerns but (1) I have stopped caring so much about rigor a while ago and just rely on my gut instinct and (2) you always confuse me with your comments. anyways, re: your last comment. I thought u meant and that the probability of flipping tails and then heads is positive. but now I don't see what you mean by "the analogous property is not proven for the bacteria population". we are looking at populations that do reach $M$ infinitely often. re: your second to last comment, let's define $A_n$ first rather than asking if some sets are in $A_n$

Comment: @Hans $A_n := \{s(0)=N \bigwedge s(t_1)=\dots = s(t_n) = M$ for some $0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \bigwedge s(t) \not = M \forall t \in \{1,\dots,t_n\}\setminus\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ and $s(t_n+1) \not = 0\}$. In particular, we do not insist on forever survival. I guess the $B(n,k)$ and $B(n,k=\infty)$ you wrote are in $A_n$. Does all of this appease you?

Comment: One situation in which people demand rigor is when the audience can not feel the author's gut instinct. This was exactly the case for me. That was also the reason I constructed the event $B(n,k)$ and posed the question. It is ironic that you urged @mbartczak to read your proof using the very adjective "rigorous" that you now reject. But let us not dwell on these rhetorical issues but concentrate on clarifying your proof, at least for me, shall we? Only now, after reading these more rigorous restatements, I see your intent.

Comment: In the proof of Claim 1. I think it would be even clearer if we simply define $A_n$ to be the event the population visits the $M$ for the $n$'th time. 
In the definition of the mapping, the right-hand side of the inequality is a probability, yet the left-hand side is not. A probability function may be missing on the left-hand side. Yet this definition confuses me. What do you mean by "sparsify"? Does it mean taking a subsequence of the original sequence $(N_1,N_2,\cdots)$? It seems $(N_1,N_2,\cdots)$ is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @Hans I understand that rigor can convey my gut instinct. Nearly always on this site, though, I've been able to convey it in comments if it was not initially conveyed. You have been an exception. Also, I don't understand why you and many others in the world make these 'hyprocritical'/'gotcha' kind of arguments -- I used 'rigorous' as a comparative word when I said it to mbartczak; I don't know what you were trying to imply... Anyways, I'm fine just focusing on the math (if you stop small jabs of claims of hypocrisy or whatever). In regards to your last comment, I prefer the definition I gave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100689/discussion-between-hans-and-mathworker21).

Comment: @Hans done. you might have to check spam.

Comment: What did you arrive at?

Comment: @mbartczak obviously it's correct. have you read it? there are some details that need to be added, but there's no way you can read the solution and not agree it is essentially correct. hans and I discussed the details that need to be added, and I'll add them when I'm not feeling lazy

Answer (score 2):

*Notice: this is a draft, it lays a context for those who would like to research.*

Let $X_N$ the number of bacteria the next day, considering $N$ bacteria the current day. Since replication and death are independent, the expected value of $X_N$ (with $N>0$, else $X_0=0$) is: $$\mathbb{E}(X_N)=N+pN-qN=N+pN-p(N-1)=N+p$$

Now let's define a markovian process $(Y_n)$ with $Y_0=N$ and $Y_{n+1}=X_{Y_n}$. Then $$P_N=\mathbb{P}(\exists n,Y_n=0)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{Y_n=0\}\right)$$
Note that $P_N\leq\mathbb{P}(Y_n\to0)$ and these quantities have different meanings.

First, $\{Y_n=0\}$ is an increasing sequence of events, because $X_0=0$. Therefore $$P_N=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(Y_n=0)$$

Second,
$$\mathbb{E}(Y_{n+1})=\mathbb{E}(X_{Y_n})=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X_{Y_n}|Y_n))$$
$$\begin{align}
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty X_k\mathbb{P}(Y_n=k)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb{E}(X_k)\mathbb{P}(Y_n=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(k+p)\mathbb{P}(Y_n=k)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(Y_n)+p(1-\mathbb{P}(Y_n=0))
\end{align}$$
with Tonelli's theorem (positive random variables). Therefore, by induction, $$\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=N+pn-p\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}(Y_i=0)$$
and especially $\mathbb{E}(Y_n)\geq N$. Also $0\leq Y_n\leq N2^n$ hence $$\mathbb{P}(Y_n=0)\leq1-\frac{1}{2^n}<1$$

Comment: So you take the limit and prove that probability of extinction is $\leq 1$ or did I miss something?

Comment: @mbartczak As I mentioned before anything else, this is only a draft for the time being. I plan to work out this problem later, when I have some free time.

Comment: Where do you get $N+pN-qN=N+pN-p(N-1)$? I do not see how $\frac1{2^n}$ gets into the final inequality.

Comment: @Hans That's the definition of $q=p(1-\frac1N)$. Then, $N\leq\mathbb{E}(Y_n)\leq N.2^n.\mathbb{P}(Y_n>0)$ therefore $\mathbb{P}(Y_n>0)\leq\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: OK. I got confused by the phrasing of the last inequality since I thought this came from the second last inequality following "by induction".

Answer (score 0):

(*query on the exact terms of the problem, too long for a comment*)

One bacterium, at time $t$ , with an extant population $n(t)$, has
 - $p$ , constant, probability to generate an additional bacterium, so that it contributes $+1$ to $n(t+1)$;
 - $q=p(1-1/n(t))$, depending on $n(t)$,  probability to die and contributing $-1$ to $n(t+1)$;
 - and consequently $r=1-p-q$ probability of just surviving and contribute $0$ to $n(t+1)$.

This is a classical [birth-death process][1] ,  which fundamentally is continuous in time, referring to live organism as bacteria.
The standard approach is to assume that in a small interval $\Delta t$ the probability of having more than one birth/death is negligible (higher order infinitesimal
wrt $\Delta t$).
In the post, the example of two bacteria that replicate in one day hints that the adopted discretization in time is not obeying to the above hypothesis.
Although it would be possible to reduce the time unit from a day to an hour, or even less,  so as to achieve that the hypothesis could be realistic,
it seems that the OP is considering the one day lapse as a sort of "juvenile quisciency" of no fertility and no mortality.

*Is this the correct interpretation of the scheme being adopted ?*

Comment: Right, this is what we would expect for large $N$, but this doesn’t tell us much about the probability of extinction, because extinction usually happens when there are few bacteria, in which case this estimation is likely to be less accurate.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer there was no estimation here. what G Cab said is true for every $N$ and gives the expected amount of growth on a given day. However, it is indeed not useful for your question of the probability of extinction.

Comment: Two observations but not sure what to do with them: (1) This means $N(t) - pt$ is a martingale.  (2) The constant positive drift reminds me of the basic $\pm 1$ _asymmetric_ random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ which also has a constant positive drift.  In that case the return-to-zero prob is $\alpha^N$.  BUT in that case the variance (in each step) is constant, whereas here the variance would increase with $N$.  Based on this, I would not be surprised if the extinction prob is bigger than any exponential...

Comment: @GCab I tried exactly what you did, but the issue with that kind of argument is that it could never rule out that the extinction probability is always $1$. But for $q = p(1-\frac{1}{N})$, the extinction probability is always $1$. See my answer below.

Comment: @mathworker21: re-examining the problem I realized that the proper schematization of the process needs to be further clarified and recasted my answer into a query

Comment: @GCab see my answer above

Comment: @mathworker21: sorry, I do not have enough theoretical bases to follow your explanation. But, you consider $p \in (0,1)$, which means that $q+p$ might be greater than $1$, i.e. that bacteria can replicate and die in the same day ?

Comment: @GCab - see 2nd comment below the OP (written by the OP author).  He clearly says the bacteria can replicate and die in the same day, i.e. all four combos are possible.  Also the first line of the question text says "At the end of the day..." so I would interpret this as discrete time, not continuous.

Comment: @antkam what is wrong with my answer :(

Comment: @mathworker21 - I did not downvote your answer, and I havent had time to read it in detail.  Hopefully I will have time over the weekend.

Comment: @antkam I'd really appreciate if you read my answer. It's starting to bother me that it has just been sitting there with a minus one for all this time and that other people are answering.